# IISNode with Windows 2012 not running my js

Tags: node.js, iisnode

I installed `iisnode` and I started `iis` and I call `localhost`. This serves up the default website of `iis`. I moved my files to `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\scriptzerprod` and created a website in `iis` to point to that directory.

When I go to `localhost/scripterprod`, I am met with a list of all the `.js` files including the `server.js` that I need run by `iisnode`.

Here is my web.config:

```
<handlers>
  <add name="iisnode" path="server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
</handlers>
```

Yet I still see the list of files, any help?

Comment: I have exactly the same issue! In my case, the server.js file is downloaded to the client when I navigate to it, rather than the file being executed.